# Add unallocated space to sda1 in Ubuntu VM VMware

Tags: partitioning, gparted, vmware

I expanded maximum disk size to 100gb in VMware and now I'm trying to add the 50gb of unallocated memory to sda1 using gparted. But I cannot do that:

[Attempt to resize sda1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxevr.png)

In all tutorials I followed so far the solution was to turn off linux-swap with swapoff, but for me linux-swap is missing, as well as the swapoff option when right-clicking any of the partitions:

[Screenshot of partitions and unallocated memory in gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygqtI.png)

Nor can I unmount sda5 (or anything else for that matter):

[Attempt to unmount sda5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFvuU.png)

How do I make sure the VM has more memory?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expand a mounted partition,and you cannot unmount an active root-filesystem. Yhats why the partitions are marked with the locked-key sign

You will have to boot your VM from the install image (live-media / CDROM) and then do the operation from there.

You will have to expand the extended partition /dev/sda into the unallocated space, and the expand /dev/sda5 wirgin the exteded partition.